# Recommended approach for parallel spring batch jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

The Spring Batch Integration documentation explains how to use remote chunking and partitioning for steps, see

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#externalizing-batch-process-execution

Our jobs do not consist of straightforward reader/processor/writer steps. So we want to simply have whole jobs running in parallel, with each job being farmed out to different partitions.

Is there already a pattern for this in Spring Batch? Or would I need to implement my own JobLauncher to maintain a pool of slaves to launch jobs on?

Cheers,
Menno

Answer (score 3):

Spring Batch specifically takes the position of not handling job orchestration (which your question fundamentally is about).  There are a couple of approaches for something like this:

- Distributed Scheduler - Most distributed schedulers have the ability to execute tasks on multiple nodes.  Quartz has a distributed mode for example.
- Using remote partitioning for orchestration - Remote partitioning executes full Spring Batch steps as slaves.  There's no reason those steps couldn't be job steps that execute a job.
- Message driven job launching - Spring Batch Integration (a child module of Spring Batch) provides the facilities to launch jobs via messages.  Another approach would be to have a collection of slaves listening to a queue waiting for a message to launch a job.  You'd have to handle things like load balancing between the slaves some way but this is another common approach of handling job orchestration.

Comment: Isn't it job execution, rather than job orchestration, as I'm not interested in work flow between jobs? I already use Spring Batch Integration for message driven job launching. But as I started thinking of how to best implement parallel jobs I was unsure whether to have multiple Job Launchers, one on each slave, sharing a single Job Repository. Or to have one main Job Launcher which can handles the job distribution/balancing. But slaves would need a shared Job Repository anyway to store the Job Contexts for job failure/restart. The same for Remote Partitioning with job steps. Hence my query.