# How to control the number of parallel Spring Batch jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have a report generating application. As preparation of such reports is heavyweight, they are prepared asynchronously with Spring Batch. Requests for such reports are created via REST interface using HTTP.

The goal is that the REST resource simply queues report execution and completes ([as described in documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer)). Thus a TaskExecutor has been provided for the JobLauncher:

```
    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As the reports are really heavyweight, only a specified number of them can be produced at a given time. Hoping to be able to configure Spring Batch to produce 2 instances at a time only, *concurrencyLimit* has been specified:

```
    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="taskExecutor">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
            <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="2" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Unfortunately, when 2 jobs are already running, the launch job call is blocked:
    jobLauncher.run(job, builder.toJobParameters());

Apparently jobLauncher immediately attempts to execute job. I would imagine it rather queue job for execution as soon as a thread is available. This way I could scale my application by simply adding additional processing instances, all using the same job repository database.

Similar question was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304831/recommended-approach-for-parallel-spring-batch-jobs). I'm about to start exploring [Spring Batch Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html) but I'm not sure if that's the right direction.

My usecase does not seem that uncommon to me, should't there be a widely discussed pattern for it that I am apparently unable to find?

Thanks
f

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` isn't recommended for heavy use since it spawns a new thread with each task.  It also does not support more robust concepts like thread pooling and queueing of tasks.

If you take a look at the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, it supports a more robust task execution paradigm with things like queueing of tasks and using a thread pool instead of spawning random, un-reused threads.

You can read more about the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` in the javadoc here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html

Comment: Additionally, you will be able to set the number of Threads in the thread pool.

Answer (score 6):

That helped, many thanks. After replacing SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor I have exactly what I need. Code:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor jobLauncherTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(executorsPoolSize);
    executor.setCorePoolSize(executorsPoolSize);
    return executor;
}
```

Thanks
f