# Multiple Spring Batch instances for robustness and scalability

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

My batch use case looks like a common pattern, yet I'm not sure if Spring Batch is designed to work as I expect. Many thanks in advance for clarifications and suggestions.

There can be a number of spring-batch based applications responsible for tasks processing. Processing requests come via REST resource, hence *ThreadPoolTaskExecutor* is used (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877797/how-to-control-the-number-of-parallel-spring-batch-jobs/30886595#30886595)). JobRegistry is based on JDBC, all instances share exactly the same configuration.

What I want to achieve is a situation where each node can process any job that has been submitted. This way I can scale my solution out as load grows - I would simply add new instances that would process queued requests. Solution is also robust: if any node dies, its tasks are automatically handled by a different node.

But it does not work this way with Spring Batch apparently. Each node seems to handle the tasks that were handled on that very node. Even if node A has 1000 items in the queue and node B does nothing, it will not take any of the A's load.

That's because how SimpleJobLauncher works - it simply queues a task into taskExecutor after creating a respective JobExecution:

```
JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobRepository.createJobExecution(job.getName(), jobParameters);
this.taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable(job, jobParameters, jobExecution) ....
```

I don't think I need job partitioning - it does not seem to be the usecase. So how do I achieve robustness and scalability with Spring Batch?

Thanks 
f

Comment: I think my scenario is a misuse of what Spring Batch is designed for, at least from what I understood from how SimpleJobLauncher works. It is the only JobExecutor implementation provided and it is simply designed to work locally.





But really, isn't there a way to scale the solution by adding more instances using the same JobRegistry?