# SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor not releasing threads

Tags: java, spring, partitioning

I am running several spring batch partitioning jobs from within the same JVM instance. Each is configured to use 3 threads but every time a new job starts I see in the logs that `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` keeps increasing its thread number.

so first jobs shows:

> 09:53:02.370 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO...
>   
> 09:53:02.370 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] INFO...

and next jobs shows:

> 09:53:02.370 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3] INFO...
>   
> 09:53:02.370 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-4] INFO...

I would have expected each new job to use threads 1 and 2 and not create new ones...I am shutting down the job each time but can post code if needed.

Comment: What is configured? The `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` just creates a new thread for async execution. If that isn't what you want properly configure async processing (which apparently you haven't done).

Answer (score 11):

[`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) does not reuse threads. Furthermore [`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) by default creates unlimited threads.

For reuse threads you need to use [`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html).

Read below for more information:

https://egkatzioura.com/2017/10/25/spring-and-threads-taskexecutor/

https://egkatzioura.com/2017/10/25/spring-and-async/

https://egkatzioura.com/2017/10/25/spring-and-threads-transactions/

[How to control the number of parallel Spring Batch jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877797/how-to-control-the-number-of-parallel-spring-batch-jobs#answer-30878217)

Comment: Thanks. wish I could give you 2 upvotes for the link - rare case where links are useful.